# VS2010 express beta2 - no add reference dialog, no open file/project dialogs

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Just installed VS2010 express for Windows Phone last night. Install went smoothly. It creates a project, compiles, and deploys the app to the emulator.

Here's the problem: When I try to "Add Reference" through the Project menu, I do not get the Add Reference dialog box. Same thing if I right click References in the solution explorer and click Add Reference. That's not all. "File...Open" and "File...Open Project" also fail to throw up an open file dialog box. When attempting any of these actions, the IDE quickly loses and regains focus. Even pressing a keyboard shortcut (Ctrl+O) causes the IDE to quickly lose and regain focus, but no open file dialog box appears.

This is what I have tried, not particularly in this order:
1. Turned off UAC
2. Monitored file and registry access using Process Monitor during a File...Open operation. File activity showed mostly "SUCCESS" with a few "FAST IO DISALLOWED" and a few "INVALID DEVICE REQUEST" results. Registry activity showed mostly "SUCCESS" with some "NAME NOT FOUND" and a few "BUFFER OVERFLOW" results.
3. Created a new, clean Windows account to run the IDE from
4. Forced a test project to add a reference to "System.Xml.Linq" by editing the ".csproj" project file. Project failed to load in the IDE.

I don't have these problems at all on 2 other Windows 7 computers with VS2010 C# express beta 2 installed. One machine is 32bit and the other 64bit, both Home Premium edition.

My system: Windows 7 Home Premium, 64bit
Other Visual Studio products installed: VS2008 C# express, VS2008 C++ express

One other thing to note: Several months ago I installed the non-phone distribution of VS2010 C# express beta 2, and I had the same exact problems. Back then I chalked it up to being beta and went back to VS2008 C# express, where I do not have these issues.

Comment: You're using a beta (and an outdated beta at that) and there are bugs... and you're surprised? The Release Candidate came out a month ago.

Comment: As OP is still in this community.Please accept any of the below as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Matt, if you're still reading this post, I have a solution:

Do you have the Tablet PC Input Service disabled?  Enable and start it.  This was suggested to me over on the MSDN forums, and it worked for me immediately.  I have this service disabled, but I turned it on, fired up VS2010, and it just worked right off.  I confirmed this solution by turning the service *off* again, starting VS2010, and noting that it breaks once again.  Turned the service on once more, started VS2010, and it works perfectly.  Amazing.

I do not think it's acceptable to require this particular service just for VS2010 to function correctly.  Hopefully they fix this in the inevitable service pack.  FYI, I had this service disabled because I turn off all services I don't require.  So now I have two "wisptis.exe" tasks eating up ~8MB of RAM and starting every time I turn on the PC.  Or I can shut the service off again and just resort to my previous workaround.  haha

Comment: David, I eventually stumbled upon this too. This was in fact the cause for me.

Comment: Same here on an old development system. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here is a work around.

Just run `wisptis.exe` from command line and start the visual studio.

If you don't wanna run each and every time you restarts the computer,then just put wisptis.exe in a .bat file and move it to the startup folder,so that it will be automatically executed on each and every startup.

**EDIT 1** :- Or else just press 'WIN'+'R' and type 'wisptis' and press 'Enter'.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the exact same problem. I'm running VS2010 Express on Windows 7 (x64). Re-enabling the "Tablet Input" service "fixed" the problem.

VS2010 has always worked fine, and then suddenly for no apparent reason "ctrl-O", "Add Reference", "Open Project", and other similar functions stop working.

No amount of repair/uninstall/reinstall would fix the problem.

I always disable the "Tablet Input" service on Win 7, because I use a Wacom tablet, and dislike the visual notification of (tablet) mouse clicks this service causes. VS2010 has so far been working fine in this setup with Tablet input service disabled, but then suddenly the problem arose, and I had to re-enable the "Tablet Input" service to make it go away.

I have another computer with the exact same setup - Win 7 (x64), VS2010 Express, Wacom table, and disabled "Tablet Input" service - and here VS2010 is still working just fine. Both computers also have almost identical software installed and updates installed, so I still have no idea where the difference lies.

Has anyone had more luck in finding the root cause?

I also use Power Toys, but I have not been able to correlate this installation with the problematic behavior of VS2010.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having close to the same issue with the exception that my New | Project dialog works, but Add Reference and Ctrl + O just cause the interface to lose focus and regain focus without every launching the dialog. I have tried running devenv /ResetAddin and devenv /ResetSkipPkgs, but neither helped. I have UAC turned off as well. I don't experience the issue with VS2008.

Here's my setup:

- Windows 7 Ultimate x64
- Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate RTM
- Visual Studio 2008 Team System Developer Edition with Team Explorer 2008 and VS2008 SP1

The only addins I run:

- GhostDoc
- .NET Reflector

Other Related Products I run:

- Microsoft Expression Studio 3
- SQL Server 2008 Developer Edition with SP1

Comment: Don't know why but a couple restarts later and just about to report it as a bug, I decided to test it one more time and it worked, so I have no clue what caused it.

Answer (score 0):

tonight I uninstalled the VS2010 Express beta 2+phone tools and installed the now final RTM VS2010 Express C#.  It STILL had the problem!  For kicks, I tried importing a VS2008 project because it has some extra references in the project, and I was curious how they would be handled.  The project imported successfully, but compiled with errors that it couldn't find a reference for a SyndicationFeed object, even though the reference for it was successfully added to the References list upon import.  I remove the reference (System.ServiceModel.Web), hold my breath, and try to Add Reference one more time.  Amazingly, the Add Reference dialog pops up, I add the reference back, recompile and bingo.  File...Open and File...Open Project now throw up the proper file open dialogs as well.

To be sure this isn't a fluke only related to importing an old project, I shut down VS2010, start it back up, create a brand new project and try Add Reference.  It works still.  The File/Project dialogs also show up.  I have no idea how, but importing a VS2008 project apparently made VS2010 correct itself on my machine.

Thank you for replying to my post.  After hours of Googling over the past few days, your post is the first I've seen of anyone else having this issue besides me.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround, but it's annoying having to do this:
1. Create a new project
2. Close VS2010, don't bother saving the new project
3. Start VS2010 again, and everything works as it should.  I can access the Add Reference dialog, and I can do a File...Open and Open Project from the menu and toolbar.

If I close VS2010 and start it again, it is broken once more.  Performing my workaround fixes it again for that session.

Still looking for a permanent solution.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out a work-around. If I temporarily disable the Power Tools, the original Add References dialog opens fine. After adding my references, I can enable the Power Tools again.